# Encode multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset and its first three columns look like this:

```
 Manufacturer           Model     Type
1          Acura        Integra   Small
2          Acura         Legend Midsize
3           Audi             90 Compact
4           Audi            100 Midsize
5            BMW           535i Midsize
6          Buick        Century Midsize
7          Buick        LeSabre   Large
8          Buick     Roadmaster   Large
9          Buick        Riviera Midsize
10      Cadillac        DeVille   Large
11      Cadillac        Seville Midsize
12     Chevrolet       Cavalier Compact
13     Chevrolet        Corsica Compact
14     Chevrolet         Camaro  Sporty
15     Chevrolet         Lumina Midsize
16     Chevrolet     Lumina_APV     Van
17     Chevrolet          Astro     Van
18     Chevrolet        Caprice   Large
19     Chevrolet       Corvette  Sporty
20      Chrylser       Concorde   Large
21      Chrysler        LeBaron Compact
22      Chrysler       Imperial   Large
23         Dodge           Colt   Small
24         Dodge         Shadow   Small
25         Dodge         Spirit Compact
26         Dodge        Caravan     Van
27         Dodge        Dynasty Midsize
28         Dodge        Stealth  Sporty
```

Now I would like to encode those text into numerical values. How can I do it? Note, I need to do normalisation to the whole dataset after this step. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `data.frame(lapply(type.convert(my_data), as.integer))` should do the trick

Comment: First I do not know what or why you are doing this, but the numbers are encoded by ordering the vectors in alphabetical manner. eg

Comment: I solved it. Thanks:)